# Is it possible to download and execute an uncompiled dart file (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make an extension based app, where you can download extensions to the app to add features/widgets. Could I somehow run an uncompiled dart file downloaded from a server that stores the .dart files?

```
download(file.dart)
compile(file.dart)
storeInPersistentDirectory()

if (dartFile.exists) {
  ClassFromDownloadedFile.sayHello()
}
```

The aim is to decrease the app size by storing all of the data related to an extension in the dart file, (classes, json and images in the form of a string...). Users might want to download features, while some don’t need them, in which case they shouldn’t need to download a large app with many features that they will never use, so the initial app size remains small.
Thank you for anyone who knows anything relating to this in advance!

Comment: No.  See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14330

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible. You can download a 'resource' such as image/video/mp3 etc. You can even download the dart file but can't compile and execute.

Answer (score 0):

there is a concept in dart and other modern languages called reflection(mirroring).

> Reflection allows us to examine and modify the structure and behavior
>   of a program at runtime.

search about it and check the below links for more information.

1. [dart document](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-mirrors/dart-mirrors-library.html)
2. [Understanding Reflection and Annotations in Dart](https://dev.to/graphicbeacon/understanding-reflection-and-annotations-in-dart-4kn1)

I recommend searching for RMI too.